# InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`could not be located

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor

i'm trying to do this but with my models from Azure.
http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Join-tables-and-return-result-into-view-usi

I have no errors in code but my index can't run.
And before you write it - Yes, i have using System.Collections.Generic; in code.

What i can do with it?

#edit, code here. It's almost same like in example...

View class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace WebApka.Models
{
    public class TestWidok
    {
        public Sesje sesjeyo { get; set; }
        public Pracownicy pracownicyyo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApka.Models
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        List<Sesje> sesje = new List<Sesje>();
        List<Pracownicy> pracownicy = new List<Pracownicy>();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var TestWidok = from s in sesje
                            join st in pracownicy on s.SPId equals st.PId into st2
                            from st in st2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new TestWidok { sesjeyo = s, pracownicyyo = st };
            return View(TestWidok);
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@page
@model IEnumerable<WebApka.Models.TestWidok>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3e</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.sesjeyo.SDomena</td>
            <td>@item.sesjeyo.SUzytkownik</td>
            <td>@item.sesjeyo.SUwagi</td>
            <td>@item.pracownicyyo.PImieNazwisko</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Please show **your** code

Comment: How did you add data to `sesje` and `pracownicy`？ It seems that both of them are empty.

Comment: From azure. App can display data from tables but i need to join tables, so now i have problem with it :/